# Cartoon movie where humans go to a new world and are treated like gods, play in a soccer-like game

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

It is a cartoon movie.

2 people (along with a pet) go to a new place where those people think of our 2 people as gods.

All I remember is (at last) soccer-like match, the goal is like a basketball ring, but the ring is perpendicular to the ground. Our 2 people win the match with the help of their pet, who acts as the ball in the last moment and goes into the ring.

Of all the people of that new land, only one person (minister of that land I suppose) knows our 2 people are not gods, but humans. He says it by saying - "TO ERR IS HUMAN".

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This sounds like [The Road to El Dorado](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_to_El_Dorado) to me. The soccer match is exactly as you describe with the perpendicular hoops, and I believe there is an armadillo like creature that rolls up into a ball to help them.

This detail doesn't exactly match your question, but I think it's close enough, from Wikipedia:

> Tzekel-Kan notices Miguel received a small cut and realizes the two are not gods, since gods do not bleed

Comment: The "soccer" game is called Ullamaliztli and was an Aztec sport.Teams have to knock the ball through a hoop to score, but have to use their hips instead of their feet.

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer. The Chief at one point drops "Hey, to err is human" to Miguel, throwing back a line Tulio had proclaimed earlier in the film. This is the only indication we get in the whole film that he knows, and it's unclear how long he's known. Tzekel-Kan also discovers this fact, as you've quoted.

Comment: It's tough to be a god... 

Comment: You're not a god? You *lied* to me?